# How can two Oracle Spatial shapes be disjointed and interacted at the same time?

Tags: oracle-spatial

This Oracle Spatial query indicates a polygon and a line have interaction but also that they are disjointed.
How can that be?

```
--disjointed but interact???
SELECT lines.pavement_key, poly.SUB_DISTRICT_NAME_UPPER ,
   SDO_GEOM.RELATE(lines.shape, 'DETERMINE'  , poly.shape,.5) detemination,
   SDO_GEOM.RELATE(lines.shape, 'ANYINTERACT', poly.shape,.5) ANYINTERACT
FROM DW_RAH_PAVEMENT_SECTIONS_DIM lines join DW_SUBDISTRICT_MASTER_DIM poly 
on MDSYS.SDO_ANYINTERACT(lines.shape, poly.shape)='TRUE'
where POLY.SUB_DISTRICT_NAME_UPPER='CRAWFORDSVILLE'
and LINES.PAVEMENT_KEY in (1003);
```

[image]

below is a map image which shows the line is actually in the polygon

[image]

Comment: That is totally odd indeed. Can you give some additional details ? 1. The full Oracle version. 2. If 12.2 or better, is spatial vector acceleration enabled ? If no/yes, what happens if you enable/disable it ? 3. Check that the shapes involved are valid.

Comment: Ultimately it will help if you can share the two geometries involved so we can try it out. And I suggest logging a service request with oracle support.

Comment: Most likely thing is that the polygon is invalid, as @AlbertGodfrind say's with out the actual data its hard to say for sure.

Comment: Perhaps there is something odd in DETERMINE? Your query seems to select just features which have ANYINTERACTION so DISJOINTS should never forward to DETERMINE. What if you query if DISJOINT is true instead of using DETERMINE? Does `where POLY.SUB_DISTRICT_NAME_UPPER='CRAWFORDSVILLE'
and LINES.PAVEMENT_KEY in (1003);` select only one row from both tables?

Comment: I actually just looked at a similar case where results where inconsistent. It was due to an invalid polygon: the polygon had the wrong orientation (clockwise instead of counter-clockwise).  You should verify your polygons and correct them using `SDO_GEOM.VALIDATE_GEOMETRY()` and `SDO_UTIL.RECTIFY_GEOMETRY()`. If that fixes your issue, then enter that as an answer to your own question.